# creating oauth login flow for java desktop application

Tags: google-drive-api

I was watching the java quickstart video for the google drive API and in that video it is 
mentioned that when developing real time console application the login flow should be done by :

1. starting a web browser in the local machine.
2. opening the native browser and taking the user directly to the authorization link.
3. making the redirection link as the local host and then let the local server receive the code and then shut down the browser and continue with you app.

but i have no idea how to execute these steps any idea or guidance???

Answer (score 0):

The tiny application on [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java) implements these steps. Use "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as your redirect URL.